# Is it possible to declare a view query for a cursor in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
DECLARE
TARGET_CURSOR record; 

BEGIN
    
set search_path to "public"; 
for TARGET_CURSOR in 
    select * from
        (select master_code, tag, value_today, time_today, value_before, time_before from
        (select tag, value_today, time_today, value_before, time_before from
        (select tag, value as value_today, inputtime as time_today
        from "public".t_hmi_data_test
        where inputtime = date_upper) today
        inner join
        (select tag_null, value_before, time_before from
        (select tag as tag_null, value as value_before, inputtime as time_before
        from "public".t_hmi_data_test
        where inputtime = date_lower) db) before
        on today.tag = before.tag_null) hmi
        inner join
        (select master_code, tag as tag_null
        from "public".t_activedata_master_test) master
        on hmi.tag = master.tag_null) sorted_hmi
```

Please excuse the poorly written joined query view (its a draft), but I was wondering if I can declare a view query as a lookup table for a cursor.

The cursor is part of a stored procedure, and though I am not popping any errors, logic more further down the line which updates existing tables based on the cursor is not working.

Is it simply not possible to use a view query as a cursor? Only actual tables?

Comment: Just to clarify you don't actually have a "View" here, right? Like nowhere in this question is an actual database object "view" in scope. I think you are confusing terms, but I want to make sure since if that IS what you meant, then it may be relevant for the question.

Comment: Working on the assumption that you don't mean a literal "view" when you say "view query" or "query view", then the answer to your question is "Yes". Declaring a cursor on SQL like this is perfectly reasonable and valid. If your downstream code isn't doing what you are expecting, then it doesn't have anything to do with  using a complex sql statement for your cursor. This complex sql may not be outputting what you expect, or your code that you aren't sharing is incorrect in some way.